# Decimal places ... Convert Double value to have 0 decimal places

Tags: java

How can I format a double value such that it has no decimal places at all ie it must look like an integer.  I need this because I want to create a double array but there are some integers in the array as well,  and they look untidy in my gui eg 500.0 I want to know how to get rid of that 0.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Please show your code!

Comment: You can format the double so that it uses no `.0` if it's not needed with DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, why not just cast your doubles into integers?

```
System.out.println(2); // prints 2
System.out.println(2.242); // prints 2.242
System.out.println((int)2.242); // prints 2
System.out.println((int)2.999); // still prints 2
```

Mind you, you will need to be careful if you are working with really big numbers.

```
System.out.println((int)985652700000.9989); // prints 2147483647 due to overflow
System.out.println((long)985652700000.9989); // prints 985652700000
```

Answer (score -2):

```
/*
Mira, puedes asignar el valor de una variable 'double' 
a otra 'int' aplicando un cast, exactamente como ya lo dijo *CSCH*. 
Ejemplo:
*/    

private void mostrarValores() {        
    double d = 123.05;
    int i = (int) d;
    System.out.println("Valor int: " + i + "\nValor double: " + d);
}

/*
Eso imprime en consola: 

Valor int: 123
Valor double: 123.05
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
*/
```